# Javascript: assertion with aparently equal values resulting different

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, assert

I have this Javascript code:

```
const BaseList = {

  new: function(list) {
    this.list = list;
    return this;
  },

  sortKeys: function(key) {
    const keys = Object.keys(this.list);
    keys.push(key);
    keys.sort();
    return keys;
  }

}

module.exports = BaseList;
```

and I am testing `sortKeys` with Mocha/Assert doing this:

```
describe('#sortKeys', function() {

  it('should insert a new key in order', function() {
    const par = {'a': 'test_a', 'c': 'test_c'};
    const bl = BaseList.new(par);
    const sl = bl.sortKeys('b');
    assert.equal(sl,['a','b','c']);
  });

});
```

It happens that my test is failing, but the failure message says:

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ] == [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
```

It seems that we have two equal arrays but the assertion says they are different.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, Object instances (so Arrays) are never equal, even if they contain same data at the moment. This is because JS compares Objects by reference, not by value.

For a simple solution, just use:

```
assert.equal(sl.toString(),['a','b','c'].toString());
```

For a better/more flexible solution: [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)